# Magento 2.4 Shipping address not showing when I checkout

Tags: magento, magento2.4

When I click checkout from my Magento 2.4 site in localhost, there haven't show shipping address or shipping method,
after checkout automatically move to payment address.  When I click checkout from my Magento 2.4 site in localhost, there haven't
show shipping address or shipping method,
after checkout automatically move to payment address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you order a virtual product, the shipping address is not shown in the checkout cause a virtual product doesn't need to be shipped.

A product can become a virtual product by accident when it has attribute Weight dropdown set to `This item has no weight` in the admin. If you change this to `This item has weight`, the shipping step should show up in the checkout.

Comment: Yeah, Now I checked this, Thanks For Your Solution

Comment: Welcome, glad this fixed it for you.

Comment: Can you please accept / upvote the answer for future visitors?

Comment: yeah, I have already done